# pk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]

Tags: android, flutter, emulation, apple-m1

I have already increase the flutter android emulator `Pixel 5 API 32` memory size, but when I started the flutter app, still shows error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-dict/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 arm64.
```

this is the emulator config:

[image]

what should I do to fixed this problem? I also have tried to increase the storage to 12GB and the SD card to 2GB, still did not fixed it.

Comment: It's not about memory. It's about storage.

Comment: 8GB not enough?@MarcinOrlowski

Comment: Try to create a new AVD instead of editing the old one... while it's unclear how large `app-debug.apk` even is.